# Bitbucket server API: Finding a branch's merge-base

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-server

### Summary

Does the Bitbucket *server* (not Cloud) API offer the equivalent of the `git merge-base branch1 branch2` to find the common ancestor of two branches?

### Details

We'd like to use the Bitbucket API to determine when a feature branch is "too old" i.e. has not been rebased or merged into from master or some other main branch (develop, release, etc) for some time - say a week. I see the following REST endpoint

```
/rest/api/1.0/projects/EXAMPLE/repos/exampleRepo/commits/?since=release/1.2.3&until=bugfix'
```

That can give all commits *not on* `release/1.2.3` in the example above. In the case of a rebased branch this is fine - I'll just find the oldest branch-specific commit and its parent is the merge-base.

However some folks do merge commits to update the feature branch (e.g. `git merge release/1.2.3` while on feature branch) and the best I can come up with is to either:

1. Parse the commit message for `Merge branch 'release/1.2.3' of <repo> into bugfix` which seems brittle because someone might rewrite the merge commit message
2. Find the most recent commit with two parents, take the second on (seems to be the source branch), look for it on the source branch and, if found, use that as a basis for determining the age of the common ancenstor.

Comment: is merging a release branch doesn't make the branch not "too old"?

Comment: Your title says "Bibucket server API" : are you looking for an API only solution ? or is it ok to run regular `git` commands on a clone of the repo ?

Comment: I am looking for an API only solution. This is for a repo webhook receiver running in a lightweight way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't try it, but in theory it should work

The endpoint

```
/rest/api/1.0/projects/EXAMPLE/repos/exampleRepo/commits/?since=release/1.2.3&until=bugfix'
```

will work for non rebased branches as well. This endpoint is an equivalent of

```
git rev-list bugfix ^release/1.2.3
```

and that's exactly what you need.

```
bugfix             C1---C2---C3----C4
                  /       /     /
release/1.2.3 -R0----R1-------R2---R3
```

In that case

```
git rev-list bugfix ^release/1.2.3
```

will return

```
C4
C3
C2
C1
```

So the parent of C1 will the base for the rebase.
It won't work if the branch `bugfix` will be merged into the `release/1.2.3`

```
bugfix             C1---C2---C3----C4--
                  /       /     /      \
release/1.2.3 -R0----R1-------R2---R3--R4--R5
```

In that case you will need to find the R4 by

```
git rev-list ^bugfix release/1.2.3
```

or

```
/rest/api/1.0/projects/EXAMPLE/repos/exampleRepo/commits/?since=bugfix&until=release/1.2.3'
```

this should return

```
R5
R4
R3
```

So you need to walk through  `R5`,`R4` and `R3` and to check if `C4` is a parent.Once you have found `R4` you can take its parents and to call the endpoint

```
/rest/api/1.0/projects/EXAMPLE/repos/exampleRepo/commits/?since=R3&until=C4'
```

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer, I’ll review all this soon

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a workaround to find the merge base is to inspect the history of `release/1.2.3` :

if the history of `release/1.2.3` is regular enough, maybe you would have a better time looking at

```
.../commits/?since=bugfix&until=release/1.2.3
```

and taking the parent of the last commit from this list.

I would have suggested to add a `--first-parent` option, but the API does not seem to offer that flag.

Comment: Thanks! I have clarified what I meant by “too old”. As in. I rebasing or merges from the parent branch in some time period.

Comment: I didn't find a way to get the merge-base through the API (but then again, I haven't much experience with the API, I only read the doc) ; I edited my answer for an alternate suggestion.

Comment: Appreciate you looking anyway, I’ll review all this in more detail tomorrow